# $q.all - resolving too early?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that makes some server calls:

```
function doCalls(options) {
    var deferred = $q.defer;
    myService.doCallOne(options).then(function(response){
        myService.doCallTwo().then(function() {
            deferred.resolve();
        });
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I have an array of different options and I want to create an array of promises to pass to `$q.all`, so I do this:

```
var promiseArray = [];
_.each(optionArray, function(options) {
    promiseArray.push(doCalls(options));
});
```

Then I try to wait for them to resolve:

```
$q.all(promiseArray).then(function() {
    doNextPart();
});
```

Problem is, `doNextPart()` seems to be getting called before any of my promises resolve. Am I doing anything obviously wrong here?

Comment: `$q.defer` should be `$q.defer()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to *call* `$q.defer`, so that it didn't actually create a deferred. Your `doCalls` function calls returned `undefined`, your `deferred.resolve()` calls threw exceptions (that were swallowed by the promises), and `$q.all` immediately fulfilled with an array of `undefined`s.

You could change your code to

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
//                     ^^
```

but really you should avoid the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)! Just use

```
function doCalls(options) {
    return myService.doCallOne(options).then(function(response){
        return myService.doCallTwo();
    }).then(function(secondResponse) {
        return undefined; // you might want to omit this
    });
}
```

Comment: D'oh. Yep. That did it. Now that she works I'll rip out that antipattern!

Comment: Not sure if this is the place for a follow-up, but how do I handle possible server errors in the calls? Ie. How do I reject a promise using that preferred pattern?

Comment: You can `throw` inside `then` callbacks (the exception will be caught and the promise will be rejected with it), or you can `return` a rejected promise from the `then` callback (`$q.reject(new Error(…))`).